# How can i fix 400 (Bad Request) jquery ajax in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello guys I have a problem when I'm trying to send data by ajax and it's said that I have 400 (Bad Request) ajax errors and this is my code:

This is Html code: the rows is data of my database $row['attributes'] it has (size,brand,color......)

```
 <form id="form">
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php
          $result_attributes = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => $row['attributes'],
            'hide_empty' => false,
          ]);
        ?>
        <select id="select-wid" name="<?php echo $row['attributes']?>">
          <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach($result_attributes as $result_attribute) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $result_attribute->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $result_attribute->name; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <?php endforeach;
```

This is jquery code:

```
(function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(document).on('change', '#form', function(e) {           

                    var data = $(this).serialize();

                    e.preventDefault();

                    console.log(data);
                    $.ajax({
                      url: ajaxwp.ajax_url,
                      data: {action: 'myactionfunction', data:data},
                      type: 'post',
                      success: function(result) {
                        $('.products').html(result);
                      },
                      error: function(result) {
                        console.warn(result)
                      },
                    });

                  });
                });
})(jQuery);
```

Image from console:
[ErrorConsoleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3scxK.png)
Image from PHP:
[ErrorPhP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7x5J.png)

Comment: Is there a response body?

In the inspector go to the network tab and find the request. Select `all` from the filtering options and then reload the page.

Click on the 'Response' tab once you have the request selected.

If there is a response body it might give a clue about what is wrong with the request (error message). 
This might be a little helpful for finding the request in the network tab:
https://medium.com/@ConnorFinnegan/how-to-effectively-inspect-network-activity-in-chrome-dev-tools-fd18592a735a

Comment: Have you defined `ajaxwp.ajax_url` ?

Comment: @BrianDanowski In Response Tab i just see 0 value

Comment: @HowardE Yes and it's working